# What formula do I need to use in order to link text in one cell from sheet to a cell in another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am new to the excel language so my question will probably sound incredibly staccato. Forgive me in advanced.

Right now, I am creating a system in Excel 2016 for my company. We manage buildings and want to consolidate the hundreds of buildings into one workbook that has links within it to the Summary page. The Summary page is a detailed overview which includes the property number, the address, the particular accountant and deadline due date for certain documents. The following sheets (hundreds of them because of the amount of properties we manage) contain information about each particular property including the number, the address, the accountant, deadline due date AND other details. I am trying to link certain cells within the individual property sheets to the text within the cells of the Summary sheet.

Lets say we manage Toothfairy's buildings and they are property #1. Their property address is 1234 Sparkling Teeth Way. The accountant is M.Lacey and the documents are due on the 15th. On Toothfairy's tab, I'd like to link `B2` to the text inside `A3` on the Summary page, `B5` to the Summary page's `B3`, and `B8` to Summary page's `D3`.

However, there will be times when the Summary page is Sorted differently, depending on the user and their preference. When the Summary page is sorted, the content in the following tabs also change because right now, the formula is referencing the cell, not the text within the cell.

Is there a way that I can reference the Summary's text within a cell rather than the cell itself? I have used the formula `=Summary!A3` but that only references the cell and the text within the cell changes when the Summary page is sorted. And then is it possible to duplicate this formula for the hundreds of properties we oversee?

This is incredibly long and complicated. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Summary Page

[image: Summary]

Property Page

[image: Tooth Fairy]

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow are supposed to be about programming. If you need to import some data from Excel into your program, then ask a question here. If you just have trouble using Excel, you won't get help here.

Comment: Can you share exactly how your data is laid out? Screen shots, or even better, build tables so we can copy the text to test things out. I suspect [indirect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) or [vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) will solve your problems

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thank you Cohan. I am not to sure how to build tables since this is my first time using Stack Overflow but I can attach screen shots.

Comment: Now you understand vlookup, you can also use index() with match() which is much more flexible. Iferror() is also something you may find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, [vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is going to be your friend here. The VLOOKUP function takes 4 parameters:

- The value to search (in this case, we'll use the property number). Reference `B3`
- The Range you want to search `Summary!A:D`
- The column you want to pull the value from (starting with the first column in your range)

  - Property Name: `2`
  - Accountant: `3`
  - Statement: `4`
- If you want to allow approximate matches (usually not the case, you want exact, so use `FALSE`)

So, in your properties worksheet,

- Cell `B3`: You'll have to manually enter the property number
- Cell `B5`: Enter `=VLOOKUP(B3,Summary!A:D,2,FALSE)`
- Cell `B7`: You can simply enter `=Summary!B1`
- Cell `B8`: Enter `=VLOOKUP(B3,Summary!A:D,4,FALSE)`
- Cell `B10`: Enter `=VLOOKUP(B3,Summary!A:D,3,FALSE)`

Summary Page

[image]

Property Page

[image]

Showing formulas (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However, excel is writing that b5, b9 and b10 all have #N/A after I manually inputted the property number in b3. @Cohan

Comment: For the moment, manually reference the same value on the settings page from `B3` (`=Summary!A3`). It's possible that you have a cell formatting issue where one is a number and the other looks like a number but is actually text.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I really appreciate your help. I do have a follow up question, how might I replicate this to the other property tabs?

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it

Comment: It will be a beast to copy to a hundred different pages, but you can look up how to paste formulas in excel and use that to copy from one page to the next. You could also consider having a single page where you update the property number, but that might not work if you consistently print the full workbook (and I don't know what other data you have on the sheets). If this is a core aspect of managing your business, I might suggest you look into having someone build you a robust system with a database. I'd hate for things to fall apart due to an accidental hit of the delete key.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. I see what you're saying. Thank you...I also just uploaded another question. If you have the time, do you mind looking at it as well? You're very thorough with your responses and I appreciate that.